# Minimize function inside integral

Tags: optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

I would like to find the function $v(x)>0,x\in \mathrm{R^+}$ that minimizes $I$, where $I$ is defined as:

$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{a}^{b} v(x) \cdot x \exp(-\lambda x) \mathrm{d}x, \quad {\lambda,a} \in \mathrm{R^+}
\end{align}
$$

subject to the following constraint:

$$
\int_a^b v(x) \mathrm{d}x = c, \quad c \text{ is some positive constant}
$$

I've looked at the literature and the closest I could find was the Euler - Lagrange equation, which finds the extremum of:

$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{a}^{b} F(x, v(x), v'(x)) \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Any hints on whether my problem is well defined and what method I could use to determine $v(x)$?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here, because either $v(x)$ is always positive or you need the integral to be defined as always positive or the problem can be arbitrarily reduced by taking an $v(x)$ and either multiplying by something big or something big and negative. 

On the other hand if you are looking at magnitudes you could always reduce the expression by taking $u(x)$ and multiplying by an arbitrarily small amount.

In the former case you could basically find a lowest so long as $I$ is not zero and for the latter case you could try to find the instance where the $I$ is zero.

Comment: There is no minimum if $v$ is allowed to be negative.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to formulate the problem well. Assuming $v(x)$ is always positive, is there then a minimum? What method could I use to find it?